# Not Getting an Average when implementing a weighted custom scoring query in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, nest, scoring

I am trying to build a query that returns a list of profiles with their relevant scores. The full query is made up of many sub queries.

Each sub-query asks of a profile a question like 'Is headcount > 50'. I want the following behaviour

- returns score 1 if exists and in range
- does not get returned if exists and not in range
- gets returned with score 0 if is missing.

I then want to take an average of all the subquery scores to give me the query score. Obviously if any queried field exists and is out of range it will not be returned.

The way I have tried to do it is with a function score query. This is the final iteration of a long series of failed attempts :(.

This returns the correct profiles; but the score is always 1. I want the score to be 0.5 if headcount is in range and turnover does not exist (say).

Any help would be appreciated so much,

Thanks,

Pascal.

```
POST /api_test/_search
{
"query": {
                  "function_score": {
                     "functions": [
                        {
                           "filter": {
                              "range": {
                                 "companyProps.headcount": {
                                    "lte": "1000",
                                    "gte": "5"
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "weight": 1
                        },
                        {
                           "filter": {
                              "missing": {
                                 "field": "companyProps.headcount"
                              }
                           },
                           "weight": 0
                        },
                        {
                           "filter": {
                              "range": {
                                 "companyProps.turnover": {
                                    "lte": "1000",
                                    "gte": "100"
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "weight": 1
                        },
                        {
                           "filter": {
                              "missing": {
                                 "field": "companyProps.turnover"
                              }
                           },
                           "weight": 0
                        }
                     ],
                     "query": {
                        "filtered": {
                           "query": {
                              "match_all": {}
                           },
                           "filter": {
                              "bool": {
                                 "must": [
                                    {
                                       "bool": {
                                          "should": [
                                             {
                                                "range": {
                                                   "companyProps.headcount": {
                                                      "lte": "1000",
                                                      "gte": "5"
                                                   }
                                                }
                                             },
                                             {
                                                "missing": {
                                                   "field": "companyProps.headcount"
                                                }
                                             }
                                          ]
                                       }
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "bool": {
                                          "should": [
                                             {
                                                "range": {
                                                   "companyProps.turnover": {
                                                      "lte": "1000",
                                                      "gte": "100"
                                                   }
                                                }
                                             },
                                             {
                                                "missing": {
                                                   "field": "companyProps.turnover"
                                                }
                                             }
                                          ]
                                       }
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "score_mode": "avg"
                  }
               }

}
```